Is there any good definition of the "interesting" information contained in a string?
The most well known measurement of a string's information content is Kolmogorov complexity. By this measurement random strings contain the most information. However it's clear that the information they contain isn't very interesting or useful due to its total lack of structure. Other types of complexity measures have been defined which try to capture the amount of interesting or structured information in a string, such as sophistication and computational depth. I found this presentation which argued sophistication isn't a very good measure of complexity, and listed some properties that any function $S$ measuring the structured information of a string should satisfy:

$S(x)$ should "clearly" measure structural information (This one is non-rigorous and kind of vague.)

$S(x)$ should not be bounded

$K(x) - S(x)$ should not be bounded, where $K$ is Kolmogorov complexity

$S(x)$ should be invariant to the choice of an underlying universal Turing machine in the same way as Kolmogorov complexity


Are there any measures of interesting/structured information that satisfy these criteria? In general, what are the most promising approaches to measuring this quantity? I'm asking as a beginner to information theory interested in learning more. It seems to me that if such a thing can be quantified it would be as fundamentally important as Kolmogorov complexity.

That presentation does a much better job of describing the attempts, and the issues with them, than I expect most answers on this site to provide. There is also an associated paper, Bloem et al., Two problems for sophistication, ALT 2015, and reading it as well as its neighbours in the citation network should give you a ton of information. Given this, I think you should clarify your question: is there a particular aspect you're interested in, that is not covered by this material, and that you believe the MSE community would be able to address?

@stochasticboy321 in particular I'm wondering if the some variant of the concept of computational depth does better than sophistication and/or satisfies all of the above criteria.

I am not a mathematician. Coming from communication theory background, in information theory, Shannon Entropy is a popular measure of information contatined in a string. But I don't enough about your criteria to comment if this is even remotely connected to what you are talking about. Anyway, this is just a comment, feel free to ignore.

Note that the authors of that presentation do not actually end up defining sophistication, they're saying that they would like a measure like this that is effective. Also, before describing the desiderata for $S$, they describe a way people have attempted to capture structured information through essentially a "low-depth" model type of assumption (slides 10-14), and the rest of the presentation is really about the issues with this kind of a view, which arises once one considers the desiderata for sophistication. I'd encourage you to read the associated paper properly.

@Srini Shannon entropy is I believe similar to Kolmogorov complexity in that random strings have the highest information content. There are probably some formal connections between the two that I'm not aware of.
